# Is there an abelian group $G$ such that $|G| > 333$ and $x^3=e$ for all $x \in G$

Tags: group-theory

> Is there an abelian group $G$ such that the order of $G$ is greater than $333$ and $x^3=e$ for all $x \in G,$ given $e$ is the identity.

If the answer is yes, please give an example.

Comment: Hint: what groups do you know (of any order) that satisfy $x^3 = e$ for all $x \in G$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint make a Cartesian product of $Z_3$ by itself enough times.